# Remote call to Roxie server from Thor

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

Assuming that we have the end-point to a Roxie server of interest, I was wondering if it is possible to make a remote call to it from a bwr script on Thor, and get the number of nodes that Roxie server has.

The code would probably look like the following:

```
RoxieServerIP := 'roxie-end-point';

numNodesRoxie := someBuiltInFunctionToGetNodes(RoxieServerIP);
OUTPUT(numNodesRoxie, NAMED('numNodesRoxie'));
```

I looked into some of the built-in functions to get the number of nodes of a cluster that you are running a process on such as:

```
OUTPUT(thorlib.wuid());
OUTPUT(thorlib.nodes());
```

but I haven't seen anything where we can call out to a difference server (e.g. Roxie) and get its number of nodes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chatted with the development team today and the best way to approach what you need to do is to deploy a query to the remote ROXIE that returned how many nodes it had. So in other words, built a "diagnostic" ROXIE query that embeds the nodes() function, and then call it from your other remote location.

Hope this helps!

Bob